# git marks files as deleted

Tags: php, git, netbeans

I have a problem with Git. I am working on a small project for college. I updated Git a few days ago and it was working fine until yesterday when it started randomly marking some files as deleted. I can still work on them, but when I want to commit changes, it just deletes my files from the project. Is this something that I am doing, or is it a Git bug?

Later Edit:
This happens in NetBeans. Running git status from the command line is ok, but in NB they are marked as deleted and they get deleted upon commit

Comment: Give more details, please.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description. Maybe the files were moved and are shown as deleted, but added as new files somewhere else? If `git status` shows a file as deleted, you can use `git checkout -- <file>` to check out the file version from the current head.

Comment: I am the only one working on this project, there are no moved/deleted files. git status does not show them as deleted, rather they are marked this way in NetBeans (I forgot to mention this?). When I want to Commit from NetBeans, they get deleted.

Comment: The files are there, and git status sees them, and netbeans doesn't, do I have that right?  If so, I'd say the problem's in netbeans somewhere.

Comment: Netbeans sees them, but they are marked gray (when I hover the mouse it says "./Deleted". But I can still open, edit, run the files as usual.